# "Nice answer" badge awarded for the wrong answer?

Tags: support, badges

I reached 10 upvotes on [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4000/how-involved-should-our-employers-be-in-our-education/4053#4053) today, but for some reason the `Nice Answer` badge I got as a result was for [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65477/why-is-it-important-that-a-unit-test-not-test-dependencies/65482#65482) instead.

Now, I also have 12 upvotes for the latter answer, so the badge itself makes sense, but why now and not whenever it was that I got 10 votes on it? That question doesn't appear on my reputation page today at all:

```
+60  23 mins ago    6 votes  How involved should our employers be in our education?
+10  4 hours ago    upvote  How do you ask or get asked to speak at a software conference?
+10  6 hours ago    upvote  Should you version web applications?
+10  7 hours ago    upvote  Hard-copy approaches to time tracking
```

Should I still expect a badge for the first answer?

Comment: It's pretty cool that a mod is asking this =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the badge for the software conferences question today. Not sure how the badge mechanism works in this case, but it looks like it was a combination of a delay and the fact that I had a deleted answer that qualified for the badge as well.

Answer (score 2):

How many non deleted answers have 10 or more votes?

Answer - 53 (you have 2 answers at 10+ that have been deleted).

You have 54 Nice Answer badges.

So you actually have too many Nice Answer badges.

You won't get another real Nice Answer badge until this extra one has been "used up". It used to be that you didn't get any notification when this happened. I'm not sure why you were notified now.

Comment: Aha, makes sense. It was the notification that threw me off and made me think it was a new badge.

Comment: @Anna - I *think* there may be a process that "moves" the extra badge from a deleted post to the new one, which is why your getting the notification. One for the dev team I think.

Comment: perhaps we need to be notified about notifications which may or may not happen?

Answer (score 1):

Badges are delayed and not granted instantly. I'm guessing you'll get another one later for the second question.